# Использование List в структуре

Tags: c#, list, struct

Делаю учебную задачу. По требованию задачи необходимо использовать структуры (классы еще не проходили).
Создал следующую структуру:

```
public struct Workers
{
        public const int MAX_WORKERS_IN_DEP = 1_000_000;
        /// <summary>
        /// Список сотрудников
        /// </summary>
        private List<Worker> _workers;
        /// <summary>
        /// Кол-во сотрудников
        /// </summary>
        public int Count => _workers.Count;
}
```

С удивлением обнаружил, что при использовании структур нельзя использовать конструктор по умолчанию. И это первый вопрос - почему так?
Но поскольку нужно инициализировать List, накостылил следующим образом:

```
public void Initialization()
{
    _workers = new List<Worker>();
}
```

Второй вопрос: а как Вы решаете подобные задачки?

Answer (score 1):

`С удивлением обнаружил, что при использовании структур нельзя использовать конструктор по умолчанию.`
Всё из-за того как структура существует в памяти. Она значимый тип, она не может быть null, она копируется при присваивании...
Когда вы делаете:

```
Workers workers1 = new Workers();
Workers workers2;
```

Фактически вы делаете одно и то же.
При при создании структуры без параметров по-сути не запускается никакой конструктор, структура может тупо копироваться из шаблона. А если в ней будут проинициализированы ссылочные поля - будет вакханалия, все свежесозданные структуры будут ссылаться на один и тот-же объект, как лист.

Обходной путь вы сами и представили. Но можно всё-таки использовать конструктор с параметрами или делать List публичным.

`Второй вопрос: а как Вы решаете подобные задачки?`
Да так и решаем, я бы предпочёл делать подобные поля публичными и инициализировать следующим образом:

```
Workers workers = new Workers() { _workers = new List<Worker>() };
```

Но можно и немножечко лайфхакнуть:

```
public struct Workers
{
    public const int MAX_WORKERS_IN_DEP = 1_000_000;
    private List<Worker> _workers_inside;
    private List<Worker> _workers => _workers_inside != null ? _workers_inside : _workers_inside = new List<Worker>();
    public int Count => _workers.Count;
}
```

В данном случае мы имеем реальный _workers_inside и get на него, который его и создаёт в случае если он null;